# Icon not supporting in visual studio 2013

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, fonts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="wide wow-animation" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Material Design Icons";
            src: url("fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot?v=1.4.57");
            src: url("fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=1.4.57") format("embedded-opentype"), url("fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2?v=1.4.57") format("woff2"), url("fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff?v=1.4.57") format("woff"), url("fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf?v=1.4.57") format("truetype"), url("fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.svg?v=1.4.57#materialdesigniconsregular") format("svg");
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }
        .box-modern-media {
            position: relative;
            padding: 20px 0;
            font-size: 60px;
            line-height: 1;
            min-height: 1.3em;
            width: 1.9em;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        .mdi {
            display: inline-block;
            font: normal normal normal 24px/1 "Material Design Icons";
            font-size: inherit;
            text-rendering: auto;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            transform: translate(0, 0);
        }
        .box-modern-media {
            width: 1.7em;
        }
        .box-modern-icon {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .mdi {
            display: inline-block;
            font: normal normal normal 24px/1 "Material Design Icons";
            font-size: inherit;
            text-rendering: auto;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            transform: translate(0, 0);
        }
        .mdi-airplane:before {
            content: "\f11c";
        }

        .mdi-airplane-off:before {
            content: "\f11d";
        }
        @media (min-width: 1200px) {
            .box-modern-media {
                font-size: 85px;
            }
            .box-modern-media {
                font-size: 64px;
            }
        }
        .box-modern-icon {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
            right: -5%;
            font-size: inherit;
            color: #09b294;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
        <div class="box-modern-media">
            <div class="box-modern-icon mdi mdi-airplane"></div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works perfectly when i run it in WAMP

[Output in WAMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6tqk.jpg)

But when i run it on Microsoft visual studio 2013 it gives only a box

[Output in Visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEjYA.png)

I am a beginner and i have no idea what the problem is.I have the file materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2
in fonts file.Is it because of visual studio version?. Please help me.Thank you.

Comment: Please check the image links. Both are the same image.

Comment: sorry,its edited